# How to use WindowsPhotoGallery to display a gif image with Java?

Tags: java, image, windowsphotogallery

I use the following code to display a gif image in Java by calling a runtime command, it opens the WindowsPhotoGallery, but doesn't display my image, instead it shows a bunch of other pictures on my PC, my question is : how to pass the gif image file name to it properly, so it will open with my image.

Now I'm passing it like this : 
C:\Program Files\Windows Photo Gallery\WindowsPhotoGallery "C:/abc.gif"

## Which is incorrect, what's the right way to do it ?

```
String Command,Program,File_Path="C:/abc.gif";
Process process=null;

Program="C:\\Program Files\\Windows Photo Gallery\\WindowsPhotoGallery ";          
Command=Program+"\""+File_Path+"\"";

try { process=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(Command); }
catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Runtime.exec(String[] cmdArray)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String[])) to pass a command and its arguments.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the command line string.

for example : c:\document and settting\pic.gif = "\"c:\document and setting\pic.gif\""

Comment: I don't quite get it. My actual command look this this :

C:/Program Files/Windows Photo Gallery/WindowsPhotoGallery C:/Dir_Stock_Data/ACC.gif

I tried to put quotes around it different ways, the results are still the same. What did I do wrong ?